# Prove $\cot{x}\cot{2x}-\cot{2x}\cot{3x}-\cot{3x}\cot{x}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a problem from my textbook. I do not know how to proceed with this proof. Any help would be appreciated. Please avoid solutions involving use of complex numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried at least to replace $\cot$ by $\cos/\sin$ ???

Comment: @Jean Marie simply doing that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

There is an addition theorem for $\cot$ which says in its cyclic form that
$$
\cot(u)\cot(v)+\cot(v)\cot(w)+\cot(w)\cot(u)=0
$$
for all complex numbers $u,v,w$ in the domain of $\cot$ such that $u+v+w=0$. This can be checked directly from the definition. If you plug in your values and use $\cot(-z)=-\cot(z)$, you find the desired vanishing since $x+2x-3x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

### Method I

From the compound angle formula $\displaystyle \tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$, we have

\begin{align}
\cot(A+B)&=\frac{1-\tan A\tan B}{\tan A+\tan B}\\
&=\frac{\cot A\cot B-1}{\cot A+\cot B}\\
\cot A\cot B-\cot A\cot(A+B)-\cot B\cot(A+B)&=1
\end{align}

Put $A=x$ and $B=2x$.

---

### Method II

\begin{align}
&\;\cot{x}\cot{2x}-\cot{2x}\cot{3x}-\cot{3x}\cot{x}\\
=&\;\cot 2x\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{\cos 3x}{\sin 3x}\right)-\cot{3x}\cot{x}\\
=&\;\cot 2x\left(\frac{\sin3x\cos x-\cos3x\sin x}{\sin x\sin3x}\right)-\frac{\cos{3x}\cos{x}}{\sin3x\sin x}\\
=&\;\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin2x}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x\sin3x}\right)-\frac{\cos{3x}\cos{x}}{\sin3x\sin x}\\
=&\;\frac{\cos2x-\cos{3x}\cos{x}}{\sin3x\sin x}\\
=&\;\frac{\cos2x-\frac{1}{2}\cos 4x-\frac{1}{2}\cos2x}{\sin3x\sin x}\\
=&\;\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}\cos4x}{\sin3x\sin x}\\
=&\;\frac{\sin3x\sin x}{\sin3x\sin x}\\
=&\;1
\end{align}

Comment: In the third step how does $\sin{3x}\cos{x}-\cos{3x}\sin{x}$ simplify to $\sin{2x}$?

Comment: $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$. The compound angle formula

Comment: In Method 1, last step, there is a slight error. It should be $\cot{A}\cot{B} - \cot{A}\cot{(A+B)} - \cot{B}\cot{(A+B)} = 1$

Comment: @mettledmike Thanks. Edited.

Comment: It should be $A=2x,B=x$

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve is by using 
$$\cot(p+q) = \frac {\cot p \cot q -1}{\cot p + \cot q}$$

We know that $$ 3x = x + 2x$$

Taking the cotangent on both sides, we obtain
$$ \cot 3x = \cot(x + 2x)$$
$$ \cot 3x = \frac {\cot x \cot 2x-1}{\cot x + \cot 2x}$$
On simple rearrangement, we obtain
$$\cot x \cot 2x - \cot x \cot 3x - \cot 2x \cot 3x = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
&\cot{x}\cot{2x}-\cot{2x}\cot{3x}-\cot{3x}\cot{x}\\
=&\;\cot{x}\left(\frac{\sin{3x}\cos{2x}-\sin{2x}\cos{3x}}{\sin{2x}\sin{3x}}\right)-\cot{2x}\cot{3x}\\
=&\;\frac{\cos{x}-\cos{2x}\cos{3x}}{\sin{3x}\sin{2x}}\\
=&\;\frac{\cos{x}-\frac12\cos{5x}-\frac12\cos{x}}{\frac12(\cos{x}-\cos{5x})}\\
=&\;1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$\cot{x}\cot{2x}-1=\cot{3x}(\cot{x}+\cot{2x})$$ or
$$\frac{\cos3x}{\sin{x}\sin2x}=\frac{\cos3x\sin3x}{\sin3x\sin{x}\sin{2x}}$$
and we are done!